# How to estimate Leave One Out Cross Validation (LOOCV) in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, validation, regression, cross-validation, pattern-recognition

I want to make a leave 1 out cross validation (LOOCV) in MATLAB and I have two cells wherein I stored my data. My first cell `Original{}` is a 1x33 matrix with 1x7 in each. My second cell `Predicted{}` has the exact same amount of data as `Original{}`.

How can I make a `for` loop to take 1 subject out for testing, and 32 for training, 33 times?

I also want to know the R^2 (R-squared) of each of my cross validated values.

This is the code I tried to make:

```
%% cross validation Leave 1 out
for i = 1:33
    xcv = Predicted{1,i};   
    ycv = Original{1,i};
    sse = 0;
    N = 33; 
    for i = 1:7
        [train,test] = crossvalind('LeaveMOut',N,1);
        %crossval = xcv(train), ycv(train),xcv(test);
        sum = sse + sum ((crossval - ycv(test)).^2);
    end
end
```

Comment: What did you tried so far. Show some code. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: I've posted what I tried, can you see it?

Comment: Sorry but this is all I have, that's why I seek for help. I want to make LOOCV on my data, and this is the code I generated, but it seems like I don't know how it works.